# Django + MySQL: performance on storing multiple foreign key

Tags: django, performance

I have two models `Post` and `Item` that hope to have their `images` field, which refer to instances of a model `Image`:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

The first approach I can think of is to add a `TextField` to both `Post` and `Item`, and store the `image_instance.image.url`s of `Image` instances, so each time I want to display all images of an `item` or `post`, I obtain the `item.images` and split the string into an array, and all the urls are there.

The second approach is to add `post` and `item` field to the `Image` model as nullable foreign key field. So each time I want to display all images of a `post` or `item`, I do something like `Image.objects.filter(item=some_item_instance)`, and extract `.image.url`.

I wonder which approach is better in practice, Or there are other better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `ManyToManyField` to store the relationship between a `Post` (or `Item`) and an `Image` and then iterate across that. Have models.py like so:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

And elsewhere, pull the set of `images` from a `Post` instance and iterate across that:

```
my_post = Post.objects.first()
for image in my_post.images:
    print image.url
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take your solution. I did use `ManyToManyField` for several actual many-to-many relations, but wasn't sure it is also recommended for one-to-many (over `ForeignKey` + `related_name`).